# How can one generate a dynamic page based on variable values in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a webpage that is a very basic quiz in Javascript. Each radio button is weighted toward a specific set of variables such that the variable with the highest "score" will be the result. How can one create a new webpage with the result once you have this value?

Let's take, for example, what kind of car you would like:

```
porsche = 0
ford = 0
toyota = 0
```

And because you are a speed demon and answer accordingly, your end result is:

```
porsche = 52
ford = 16
toyota = 33
```

How can I generate HTML (or similar) which has a page with a picture of a Porsche?

```
if (porsche > ford && porsche > toyota)
{
    // generate Porsche page
}
else if (ford > porsche && ford > toyota)
{
    // generate Ford page
}
else if (toyota > porsche && toyota > ford)
{
    // generate Toyota page
}
else
{
    // a page for everything else
}
```

I of course can do the actual HTML/CSS/etc. on my own but there is no obvious way to do dynamic results pages (at least from my searches).

Comment: You can direclty manipulate the page with js, have a look at the DOM

Comment: You may also want to consider learning a framework such as [Angular](https://angular.io/) which has support for conditionals inside of the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe window.open() function helps you

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px 
tall!</p>");
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp